# Where can I find OpenCL SDK 1.1 for linux?

Tags: opencl, intel

I need the 1.1 version of OpenCL SDK to run on linux but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I suggest to ask on their own forum

Answer (score 0):

Just install the latest Intel Linux OpenCL 1.2 drivers (from http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk-xe) but for your program use an OpenCL 1.1 header if you want to make sure you're not using any OpenCL 1.2 APIs. You can get 1.1 headers from Khronos: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/. This will ensure your code with run with OpenCL 1.1 drivers (assuming that is why you're looking for the 1.1 SDK).

Answer (score 0):

Intel has recently updated the product pages and the OpenCL SDK on Linux is now branded as the Intel SDK for OpenCL Applications XE. You can download it from http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk-xe.